# How to fit long text into tab in Rave Reports

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, rave-reports

I'm making a report with a Rave Reports component in Delphi. I've come to some issues that I cannot figure out myself.

If I have a very long number or text without spaces inside, how can I fit it into the tab? My tabs have concrete widths and I don't want that very long text is truncated that doesn't fit into the tab. Is there any way to check if text is longer than tab width and then continue this text on new line? Also, is there a way for tab padding?

Regards,
evilone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would seriously consider changing your reporting engine to, for example, Fast Reports. Last i heard was Rave Reports is no longer - i may be wrong, but just doing a quick check i couldnt even get to their website.

Fast Reports has the functionality you describe.

Comment: Yeah, I have noticed this problem too. But I need to use Rave Reports in this project. I got some documentation and found a way to handle this problem. But no direct answer for this question as I see from the answers above :)